# Special Symbol or Single Quote or apostrophe in JSON String in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

`JSON` response String containing an apostrophe

This is the key and value coming from the server.

```
"name": "men’s basketball wear with free product",
```

When I'm converting this `JSON` into  `pojo response` `Future<Product>` returning me this when I print the string in the log.

> PRODUCT NAME `menâs basketball wear with free product`

[image]

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685675/escaping-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-dart)  but nothing is happening

```
replaceAll("'", "\'").replaceAll('"', "\'") 
replaceAll('"', '\\"')
```

I have tried in response class

```
Product.fromJsonMap(Map<String, dynamic> map):
        pid = map["pid"],
        aid = map["aid"],
        name = map["name"].replaceAll("'", "\'");
```

My HTTP request

```
http.Response res = await http.get(url);
```

Comment: I guess you get this JSON from an HTTP request and it's an encoding issue. Check the content-type header of the response.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this is coming from get service ` http.Response res = await http.get(url);` should I need to change at server side?

Comment: Try with `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` and check what the content-type header of the response is

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer still returning the same thing.

Comment: You could first check the response headers as mentioned before

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks  I was not able to check and change response header, I will have to manage what I have and found the solution by Richard Heap answer.

Comment: As you figured out, setting a `content-type` on the *request* isn't going to make any difference. As is typical with a `GET` you aren't actually sending any content *to* the server. You want the server to send its content back to you in UTF-8; in fact it already is - so there's nothing more you can do in the request to influence the response. The problem is that the server is forgetting to include the charset suffix with its `content-type`. Dart has a slightly unusual (for this day and age) default of LATIN-1 if the suffix is omitted. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Richard Heap answer

```
  http.Response response = await http.get('SOME URL',headers: {'Content- Type':'application/json'});
    List<dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks.
Btw, no need for `Content-Type` header, just for consistency maybe you want `Accept` header with `application/json;charset=utf-8` value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `utf8.decode()` solves the issue for me.